# how i can send a confirmation response to my API , when user click on activation link

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a confirmation message  to my API after click on activation link  , I am trying lot but failed ,
http://polestarllp.com/users/useractive.php?contranumberid=23215

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             var person = "<?php $data; ?> ";
                 $.ajax({
                     url: 'http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser',
                     //type: 'Post',
                     data:person,
                     success: function (data, xhr) {
                     alert(data.ErrorMessage);
                     if(data.Success)
                     {
                    document.location.reload();  
                     }

                     },
                     error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         console.log('Error in Operation');
                     }
                 });



         });
    </script>
<style>
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about the specific errors if any?

Comment: I am trying to do this with this code , I have only this url http://polestarllp.com/users/useractive.php?contranumberid=23215 , and i have to send response through this url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far from what you said I have understood that you're trying to send a POST request whenever a user accesses your URL. Is that correct?

In that case try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',  
            url: 'http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser',
            data: {'id' : 23215},
            success:(function(data){
                alert('Success ' + data);
            }),
            error:(function(data){
                console.error('Error ' + data);
                alert('Error has occurred');
            })      
        });
    });

</script>
```

This will send a POST request to `http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser` straight after when the page loads, with `id` parameter and its value being `23215`

If you want to get the `contranumberid` from the URL, you can embed the PHP into your JS script like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var contranumberid = <?php echo intval($_GET['contranumberid']);?>;
    $(window).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',  
            url: 'http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser',
            data: {'id' : contranumberid },
            success:(function(data){
                alert('Success ' + data);
            }),
            error:(function(data){
                console.error('Error ' + data);
                alert('Error has occurred');
            })      
        });
    });

</script>
```

Note that I've added a new line:
`var contranumberid = <?php echo intval($_GET['contranumberid']);?>;`

This will assign a JS variable to the value of the GET `contranumberid` parameter and the POST that value to `http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser`.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The script you have given in the question and the actual script in the page linked in question is slightly different. The `success` callback function was missing closing braces. Here's a better version of your JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc(id) {
        id = 23215;
            $.ajax({        
                url: 'http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser',
                type: 'post',             
                data: {'id' : 23215},
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    alert(data.ErrorMessage);   
               }        
           });
     }
</script>
```

Also, I didn't see any code invoking `myfunc()` anywhere?

Comment: I am trying to do this with this code , I have only this url polestarllp.com/users/useractive.php?contranumberid=23215 , and i have to send response through this url  @@ suggest me please

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve, but if you just want to initiate the AJAX request present in myfunc(), you can just invoke myfunc() just before the closing script tag.

Comment: wait i am changing whole script

Comment: i am trying to send a confirmation message  to My API ('http://192.168.1.102:1512/qlikapi/RegisterUser') @@when user click on  this link   http://polestarllp.com/users/useractive.php?contranumberid=23215